# Can not read from pipe if \n is missing

Tags: linux, pipe

If I use

```
printf("Message entered %s",message);
```

instead of

```
printf("Message entered %s\n",message);
```

in the code `A sample program to demonstrate how pipes are used in Linux Processes` on http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/category/pipes/ this doesn't print output.Why this? Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you have another bug: your `memset` is neither necessary (you only need one terminator to make `strlen` and `printf %s` happy) nor sufficient (if the message fills the buffer, there won't be any `'\0'`s left).

Answer (score 1):

Printing to standard output is normally line buffered. If you don't have a newline character, you need to call [`fflush(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fflush/) to make sure your output goes where you expect it to go.